# enumerate MediaFoundation sink

Tags: visual-c++, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to build a full topology in MediaFoundation, using BlackMagic Decklink cards as sources and sinks.  In MediaFoundation, there exists an easy way to enumerate sources:

```
hr = MFEnumDeviceSources(pConfig, &ppDevices, &count);
```

But for the life of me I cannot find an easy way to enumerate the sinks on a machine, and I'm coming up empty from the official documentation.  Has anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: and yet [topoedit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485862(v=vs.85).aspx) does it... and the source code is included in the windows sdk, have you looked there?